# How to change my query to get result?

Tags: mysql, select

SELECT * FROM feature_product 
WHERE  ( feature_ref_id=11 or feature_ref_id=10  ) AND ( feature_ref_id=13 or feature_ref_id=12)

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: select  *  from 
(
  SELECT * FROM product 
      INNER JOIN `feature_product` on feature_product.`product_ref_id`=product_id 
       where ( feature_ref_id=11 or feature_ref_id=12 ) 
 ) as t1
 inner join
 (
   SELECT  product_id as id FROM product 
      INNER JOIN `feature_product` on feature_product.`product_ref_id`=product_id 
      where( feature_ref_id=13 or feature_ref_id=14   ) 
 ) as t2
on t2.id=t1.product_id
GROUP BY product_id

Comment: thank you  , I find my  answer

Answer (score 1):

`feature_ref_id` can't be 11 and 13 OR 10 and 12 at the same time and hence, no data. Use `IN` instead, e.g.:

```
SELECT * 
FROM feature_product 
WHERE feature_ref_id IN (10, 11, 12, 13);
```